# Fake parallax effect using a single flat image

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, parallax

I'm trying to achieve a 'fake' Parallax effect in JavaScript using . It's really hard to describe what I mean, but I'm goint to try:

I want things on a page to move around when I hover my mouse over them. Things in the back should move less than things in the front - the usual [Parallax effect](https://github.com/404) - *except* I want to use a **flat image** to do so. Now, usually you would have to cut things out in an image editor and replace parts of the now-missing background and so on.  But I think I saw this once done in some kind of 'fake' way: by slightly stretching and compressing the background.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to find an example of this effect anymore, but I'm pretty sure it has something to do with **displacement maps**.

Is there a library for this kind of thing? Or does anyone at least know an example in another language that I can translate to JavaScript?

Comment: These demos seem relevant: http://kenshodubs.com/demos/displacement/ and http://www.soundstep.com/blog/2012/04/25/javascript-displacement-mapping/ and http://blog.yoz.sk/2010/05/pixel-bender-displacement-map-fakes-3d-effect/

Comment: If you want more than two planes, you'll need more than a single mask.

Answer (score 0):

not really sure what you're asking. but i've used spritely to quickly do a parallax scene. it does involve multiple image layers but they can be easily made. 
http://www.spritely.net/

there are also some other solutions for parallax like this one. this approach involves repeating the same image to create depth.
http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/imageparallax.html

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, [Phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz) [link](http://www.soundstep.com/blog/2012/04/25/javascript-displacement-mapping/) didn't seem relevant (I also hit the same link when I did my own research before), but when I took a deeper look at it, it was *exactly* what I was looking for.

Unfortunately, it's *really* slow, so it isn't really suited for that kind of animation I'm going for, especially with screen-filling images. I got it somewhat faster by doing some micro-optimizations, but in the end this kind of thing just seems to be too intense for today's JavaScript.

Anyway, here's what I ended up with. Maybe it helps someone, or maybe someone figures out how to speed it up in order to use it at 30 or 60 fps (Workers?). *The code isn't pretty at all, since I just messed around a bit. Use it as a starting point.*

HTML:

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="displacement.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            (function() {
                'use strict';
                var source, map, target;
                var sourceCtx, mapCtx, targetCtx;
                var loaded = false;
                var x = 0, y = 0;
                var filter;

                function render() {
                    filter = new filters.DisplacementMap(
                            source,
                            map,
                            target,
                            new filters.Point(0, 0),
                            x,
                            y,
                            filters.ColorChannel.RED,
                            filters.ColorChannel.RED);
                    filter.draw();
                }

                (function init() {
                    var img = new Image();

                    function prepareCanvases() {
                        // Create canvases and add them to the document
                        source = document.createElement('canvas');
                        map = document.createElement('canvas');
                        target = document.createElement('canvas');
                        [target, source, map].forEach(function(canvas) {
                            canvas.setAttribute('width', img.width);
                            canvas.setAttribute('height', img.height);
                            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                        });

                        // Get contexts
                        sourceCtx = source.getContext('2d');
                        mapCtx = map.getContext('2d');
                        targetCtx = target.getContext('2d');
                    }

                    // Load source image
                    (function loadImage() {
                        img.onload = function() {
                            prepareCanvases();
                            sourceCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                            img.onload = function() {
                                mapCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                                addEventListeners();
                                loaded = true;
                            };
                            // Put your displacement map here
                            img.src = 'jn-map-small.jpg';
                        };
                        // Put your image here
                        img.src = 'jn-edit-small.jpg';
                    }());

                    // Event listener
                    function addEventListeners() {
                        target.onmousemove = function(e) {
                            x = ((-e.offsetX / source.width) * 10) + 5;
                            y = ((-e.offsetY / source.height) * 10) + 5;
                            render();
                        };
                    }
                }());
            }());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

displacement.js:

```
/**
 * Based on Romuald Quantin's code
 * @see http://www.soundstep.com/blog/2012/04/25/javascript-displacement-mapping/
 */
var filters = {} || filters;
(function() {

    filters.ColorChannel = {
        RED: 0,
        GREEN: 1,
        BLUE: 2,
        ALPHA: 3
    };

    filters.Point = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x || 0;
        this.y = y || 0;
    };

    filters.DisplacementMap = function(source, map, target, point, scaleX, scaleY, channelX, channelY) {
        this.source = source;
        this.map = map;
        this.target = target;
        this.sourceCtx = this.source.getContext("2d");
        this.mapCtx = this.map.getContext("2d");
        this.targetCtx = this.target.getContext("2d");
        this.point = point || new filters.Point();
        this.scaleX = scaleX || 0;
        this.scaleY = scaleY || 0;
        this.channelX = channelX || filters.ColorChannel.RED;
        this.channelY = channelY || filters.ColorChannel.RED;
        if (this.channelX !== 0 && this.channelX !== 1 && this.channelX !== 2 && this.channelX !== 3)
            this.channelX = filters.ColorChannel.RED;
        if (this.channelY !== 0 && this.channelY !== 1 && this.channelY !== 2 && this.channelY !== 3)
            this.channelY = filters.ColorChannel.RED;
    };

    var p = filters.DisplacementMap.prototype;

    p.draw = function() {
        var sourceData = this.sourceCtx.getImageData(0, 0, this.source.width, this.source.height);
        var mapData = this.mapCtx.getImageData(0, 0, this.map.width, this.map.height);
        var targetDataX = this.sourceCtx.getImageData(0, 0, this.source.width, this.source.height);
        var targetDataY = this.sourceCtx.getImageData(0, 0, this.source.width, this.source.height);
        var pixelsLength = mapData.data.length / 4;
        var colorValue,
                alphaValue,
                ratio,
                ratioWithAlpha,
                pixelShift,
                sourcePosition,
                targetPosition,
                x,
                y;
        var i = 0;
        var map = this.map;
        var point = this.point;
        var channelX = this.channelX;
        var channelY = this.channelY;
        var scaleX = this.scaleX;
        var scaleY = this.scaleY;
        var source = this.source;
        var target = this.target;
        while (i < pixelsLength) {
            x = ((i % map.width) + point.x) | 0;
            y = (((i / map.width) | 0) + point.y) | 0;
//            alphaValue = mapData.data[i * 4 + filters.ColorChannel.ALPHA];
//            ratioWithAlpha = ratio * (alphaValue / 0xFF);
            targetDataX.data = this.setPixels(targetDataX.data, (target.width * y) + x + ((((mapData.data[i * 4 + channelX]) / 0xFF * 2) - 1) * scaleX | 0), sourceData.data, (source.width * y) + x);
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        while (i < pixelsLength) {
            x = ((i % map.width) + point.x) | 0;
            y = (((i / map.width) | 0) + point.y) | 0;
//            alphaValue = mapData.data[i * 4 + filters.ColorChannel.ALPHA];
//            ratioWithAlpha = ratio * (alphaValue / 0xFF);
            targetDataY.data = this.setPixels(targetDataY.data, (target.width * (y + ((((mapData.data[i * 4 + channelY]) / 0xFF * 2) - 1) * scaleY | 0))) + x, targetDataX.data, (source.width * y) + x);
            i++;
        }
        this.targetCtx.putImageData(targetDataY, 0, 0);
    };

    p.setPixels = function(target, pos, source, i) {
        i = i * 4;
        pos = pos * 4;
        target[i] = source[pos];
        target[i + 1] = source[pos + 1];
        target[i + 2] = source[pos + 2];
        target[i + 3] = source[pos + 3];
        return target;
    };

})();
```